# Visual basic syllable count

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to count syllabes using regular expressions. I have already counted words

```
Static word As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-zA-Z]+\s", 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled Or
System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

How do I count syllables in each word I have counted. I can count syllables in whole tectbox but can't find a way to process each word I have counted seperately. I would like to use regular expressions like I have used already if it is possible

Comment: I doubt you can count syllables with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syllables are a specific set of string over an alphabet on a given language. Different languages, sharing the same alphabet, may have different sets of syllables.
The syllables set is enumerative: i.e. you have to list all the set element to completly describe the set.

Regular expressions instead let you define a set through a property. For example, the expression /g\w{1,5}/ over the latin alphabet defines the set of all the words starting with 'g' and length between 2 and 6.

See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: i understand. so i guess my question now is, is there a way to extract each word i am counting and process the word for syllables myself for the english language. i have instructions on what defines a syllable. i just cant seem to processe each word separetely.